# Add space before inline element with Schematron

Tags: dita, schematron

I'd like to add spaces before some specific XML inline elements with Schematron, e.g. `<ph>`, but only if there isn't a space. I cannot see the issue of my rule. Could you please help?

```
<sch:pattern id="add-space-before-ph">
    <sch:rule context="ph">
        <sch:assert test="preceding::text()[not(ends-with(., ' '))]" 
                    role="warning" 
                    sqf:fix="add-space-before-ph">Add space before &lt;ph&gt;</sch:assert>
        <sqf:fix id="add-space-before-ph">
            <sqf:description>
                <sqf:title>Add space before &lt;ph&gt;</sqf:title>
            </sqf:description>
            <sqf:add position="before" match="." select="' '"/>
        </sqf:fix>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

Comment: You have two problems with the assert: first problem is that the message is displayed when the assert is not fulfilled so you need to negate its condition, second problem is that you are actually matching a text node with a certain condition instead of checking if the text node fulfills a certain condition so I think the assert should look like this: <assert test="ends-with(preceding::text()[1], ' ')"

Comment: And you should also take into account the fact that before the ph there can be more than one spaces + line breaks (XML might be pretty printed).

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks a lot. Handling the line breaks and multiple spaces is step 2. Why don't you add an answer instead of a comment? Otherwise you won't get reputation and I cannot mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Hi Radu, hi xephon, inline checking / transforming is very hard if you want to respect all possibilities. Radu's check is ok for the most of the cases, but for instance it wouldn't find this: `<p>content </p><p><ph>content</ph><p>`.

Comment: Hi Nico, for sure, especially if you'd like to support all DITA elements. This snippet is just an example for being used as a starting point for validating XLIFF files that have been created from DITA source. I plan to release these rules for XLIFF and DITA, so this will be a diligent but routine piece of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with the assert: first problem is that the message is displayed when the assert is not fulfilled so you need to negate its condition, second problem is that you are actually matching a text node with a certain condition instead of checking if the text node fulfills a certain condition so I think the assert should look like this:

```
<sch:assert test="ends-with(preceding::text()[1], ' ')" 
                  role="warning" 
                  sqf:fix="add-space-before-ph">Add space before &lt;ph&gt;  </sch:assert>
```

And you should also take into account the fact that before the ph there can be more than one spaces + line breaks (XML might be pretty printed)